# Проблема с добавлением нескольких товаров по AJAX в WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

В общем, реализовал добавление нескольких товаров с количеством в корзину по AJAX, использовал одно из решений, которое нашел в интернете, но есть две проблемы.

1. Главная проблема в том, что после добавления товара, не
   обновляется мини корзина товара, хотя в обработчике PHP вызывается
   WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments() и у меня есть хук для обновления
   корзины woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments...
2. Запросы AJAX отправляются в цикле, пока не добавил async: false,
   некоторые из запросов просто терялись, может есть более лаконичное
   решение?

**JS**

```
productsToAdd // массив с id и quantity

$(document).on('click', '.buy-tovar', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();         
    productsToAdd.forEach(function(item){
        var data = {
            action: 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart',
            product_id: item['id'],
            quantity:  item['quantity']
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
            data: data,
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('.buy-tovar').addClass("added");                      
            },
        });

    }); 
});
```

**PHP**

```
//Стандартное обновление корзины
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment' );
function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    ob_start(); 
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" class="cart">
        <div class="img-block">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/image/cart.png" alt="">
            <span><?php echo count( WC()->cart->get_cart()); ?></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php   
    $fragments['a.cart'] = ob_get_clean(); // селектор блока обертки
    
    return $fragments;
}

//AJAX обработчик
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');

function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    
    $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
    $quantity = absint($_POST['quantity']);
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
    $product_status = get_post_status($product_id);
    
    

    if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity) && 'publish' === $product_status) {

        do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);

        if ('yes' === get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true);
        }
        
         WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments();
    } else {

        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));

        echo wp_send_json($data);
    }

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Будьте добры (на будущее), старайтесь делать отдельный топик на каждый вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с обновлением мини корзины, добавил эту строчку:

```
$(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');
```

Полный код JS ( по поводу второго вопроса, советовал бы не использовать цикличную отправку, а желательно отправить один запрос AJAX с JSON, вот статья на эту тему:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754300/woocommerce-adding-multiple-items-to-the-cart-with-ajax

```
$(document).on('click', '.buy-tovar', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();         
    productsToAdd.forEach(function(item){
        var data = {
            action: 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart',
            product_id: item['id'],
            quantity:  item['quantity']
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
            data: data,
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('.buy-tovar').addClass("added");
                $(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');
            },
        });

    }); 
});
```